# How to export multiple library variants from a single NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm creating a node library that could be partially used in web browsers.

My current structure is something like:

```
package.json
lib/
    index.js
    node.js
    web.js
modules/
    some-function.js
    some-node-function.js
    some-web-function.js
    ...
```

**"lib/index.js"** is specified as **"main"** in ***package.json***

I'm using each file inside ***lib/*** to re-export functions from ***modules/*** filtered by target (all/node/web)

And I would like to use it like this:

```
import fullLibrary from "my-library";
import {someFunction} from "my-library";

import webOnlyLibrary from "my-library/web";
import {someWebFunction} from "my-library/web";

import nodeOnlyLibrary from "my-library/node";
import {someNodeFunction} from "my-library/node";
```

**BUT** keeping ***index.js***, ***node.js*** and ***web.js*** inside ***/lib***!

Currently only the first two import statements work (because index.js is pointed from package.json).

I know that I could place those files in the root of the package and it would work as expected when importing, but I was wondering if there was a way to do the same while keeping the files in ***/lib*** for cleanness.

In any case, is this the recommended way to expose multiple variants of a same library from a single NPM package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone that is having similar questions regarding libraries structure and organization.

Back then I started working with monorepos using [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org) and [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) and I haven't regret it. I think this is the most efficient way to go in terms of modularity, readability, scalability and maintainability.

Specifically, the question code would be traduced into this:

```js
import webOnlyLibrary from "@my-library/web";
import {someWebFunction} from "@my-library/web";

import nodeOnlyLibrary from "@my-library/node";
import {someNodeFunction} from "@my-library/node";
```

Comment: Do you need to do anything within your my-library package.json to support this?